# For $x \in (0, \pi/2)$ find local maximum of $S_{N,f}(x) = \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{k >0, \ k \ \text{odd}}^N \frac{\sin(kx)}{k}$

Tags: calculus

For $x \in (0, \pi/2)$ find local maximum of $S_{N,f}(x) = \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{k >0, \ k \ \text{odd}}^N \frac{\sin(kx)}{k}$

I have shown that $\frac{d}{dx} S_{N,f}(x) = \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{\sin((N+1)x)}{\sin(x)}$

I also know that $N$ is odd, hence $N+1$ is even. The zeros for  $\frac{d}{dx} S_{N,f}(x)$ are $x= \frac{k\pi}{N+1}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then 
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} S_{N,f}(x=\frac{k\pi}{N+1}) = \frac{(N+1)(-1)^k \sin(\frac{k\pi}{N+1})}{\sin^2(\frac{k\pi}{N+1})}.$$

How can I proceed?

I now saw that there was a hint on the back of my paper (I'm doing exercises), but I still need help.

> Rewrite the partial sum as $S_{N,f}(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{d}{dy} S_{N,f}(y) dy$ and use the fact that the denominator in the formula for $S_{N,f}(y)$ is increasing with $y$ for $y \in [0, \pi/2]$

Comment: $S_{N,f}$ is $C^1$ and you have found the zeros of the derivative so you have found all the possible local extremum, check the sign of the second derivative to find which ones are local maximum. And I don't understand the hint.

Comment: @user1952009 yes I have done that, please check my edit. But I can not figure out the relationshop between $k$ and $N$. And if $k= N+1$ then we have a problem.